# Sending numbers via Serialport from C# to Java

Tags: java, c#, serial-port, arduino

I'm making a Bluetooth quadcoopter using Arduino. I have no problem sending letters, but I cant seem to write or read numbers.

I'm not very good at programing so bear with me.

C# code:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int testInt = 35;
            byte[] testByte = BitConverter.GetBytes(testInt);
            serialPort1.Write(testByte, 0, 0);

            int i = BitConverter.ToInt32(testByte,0);
            label5.Text = i.ToString();
        }
```

Here I've tried to convert to send a byte, at first I just sent it directly as a string. I get the same result from both ways.

Arduino code:

```
 <code>void loop() 
{
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  if(Serial.available())
  {
    int data = Serial.read();
    if(data=='35')
     {
        digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
     }
  }
}
```

Why don't the LEDs light up? How do I read numbers from a serial port?

Comment: It's pretty hard to tell why it's not working. Have you checked if there's anything arriving at the arduino at all? Also the java code won't compile since ``'35'`` is an invalid expression.

Comment: `serialPort1.Write(testByte, 0, 0);` Your sending 0 bytes from offset 0. I assume you want to send all bytes. So the second parameter should be testByte.Length . And you are sending the value 35 while in the arduino code you send 13.

Comment: @Ralf: The arduino code is not sending anything via serial, only receiving. The ``digitalWrite`` statement is supposed to make an LED light up.

Comment: @f1sh Ah, ok. In that case the c# code is simply not sending anything.

Comment: @Ralf: serialPort1.Write(testByte, 0,testByte.Length ) did the trick, thank you :) wasted to many hours on this

Comment: @Ralf: post this as an answer below and receive your points :)

Answer (score 0):

This sends a single byte (0 to 255):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    // set up to send only one byte
    byte[] testByte = {35};
    // send one byte
    serialPort1.Write(testByte, 0, 1);
}
```

And this receives and interprets it on the Arduino:

```
void loop() {
    if (Serial.available()) {
        byte data = Serial.read();
        if (data == 35) {
            digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
        }
    }
}
```

If you think you might send a number greater than 255, it's probably just as easy to send a string. Add a new line character to the end of the string:

```
String testString = "35\n";
```

and use the new line to let the Arduino know you're done sending the code, something like this:

```
#define MAX_SIZE 5;
char button[MAX_SIZE+1];

if (Serial.available()) {
    int bytesRead = Serial.readBytesUntil ('\n', button, MAX_SIZE);
    if (bytesRead > 0) {
        button[bytesRead] = '\0';
        int result = atoi(button);
        if (result == 35) {
            digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
        } else {
            digitalWrite(13, LOW);
        }
    }
}
```